# Is it possible to build releases based on tags with a Continuous Integration system (such as Travis CI / Jenkins)

Tags: version-control, git, continuous-integration

After reading and asking about how to deal with git, Github, branching, versioning and tagging, it looks like the best way to denote a new version of software, is by marking the last commit of a specific version with a specific tag.

A structure like this can be assumed:

- Commit 1
- Commit 2: Tag 1.0.0
- Commit 3
- Commit 4
- Commit 5: Tag 1.1.0
- Commit 6: Tag 1.1.0

Where once version 2.0.0 is released, most likely a 1.1.x branch is created to maintain the 1.1 release for hotfixes, etc.

Now I am wondering how it is possible to integrate this with a CI, like Travis for example.

What I do know is that:

- A Continuous Integration system, like Travis CI, gets triggered on every *commit* to any branch, and it is possible to enable/disable this per branch.

I am struggling to figure out if it possible at all to start a build once you have *tagged* a certain commit, can anyone explain me how this can work?

Comment: Continuous Integration is the practice of merging all development work with the main development branch, and testing these changes to catch issues early. You should actually continue doing this will all merges. The problem you are referring to is actually Continuous Deployment or Continuous Delivery. There are different options depending on the toolset you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Travis and Continuous Integration systems in general is that first word: Continuous. You want it running on every commit because your tests should always be working (except when you know they're not). Running it on each tag isn't very CI-like, as it prevents the continuous part from happening, and defeats the entire point of it.

CI allows developers to catch bugs before they might've been noticed, even if your contribution docs say that you're *supposed to* have the build passing before pushing doesn't mean people listen. Travis, in particular, allows for lots of variation and multiple builds per commit with different setups, so you can test for a case that you might not think of when developing locally.

If you *really* just want to run it on each tag, you could write your build script to exit early if there wasn't a new tag defined. Travis defines [a bunch](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) of environment variables that could help you detect it.

Comment: After reading some more the last day, I may actually be talking about a sort of Continuous Deployment rather than CI, sorry if that confused anyone.